# DataTables rowGroup with server-side pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable that uses the rowGroup plugin to group rows according to the first column. (See image).

[image]

I am also usinng server-side pagination. Currently the pagination considers the number of edition rows, so if there are 40 editions (rows), at 10 editions per page that is 4 pages.

But I want to paginate based on the Primary Source (rowGroup), so that if there are 40 sources, there are 4 pages, with 10 sources (by column) on each page.

The way it works now, if a Primary Source (rowGroup) has 4 edition rows, there would be 10 - 4 sources listed on the page.

Here's some code so you can better understand what I am doing:

```
<table width="100%" id="torrents">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Source / Date / Author</th> <!--rowGroup column header !-->
            <th>Source / Date / Author</th> <!--edition row !-->
            <th>Snatches</th>
            <th class="none torrents"></th> <!-- hidden responsive + !-->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$("#torrents").DataTable({
        responsive : true,
        serverSide : true,
        pageLength: 10,
        processing: true,
        searching: false, paging : true, info: true,
        order: [],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                target: 0,
                visible: false,
                searchable: false
            }
        ],
        rowGroup : {
            dataSrc : 0
        },
        stateSave: true,
        ajax : {
            /* ajax code */
        }

})
```

Is there any way to do this -- paginate by the first column (rowGroup) -- using jQuery DataTables and rowGroup plugin with server-side pagination?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood the question - but when you are using `serverSide: true` all pagination (and sorting and filtering) logic is executed on the server. When you are deciding which records to send back to the browser for the current requested page, you have to build that data set yourself. If you want to control the `rowGroup` results DataTables applies, I expect you will have to perform the equivalent grouping logic in your server code, so the server "knows in advance" what the end result will look like in the DataTable. So, it's a server logic question, not a DataTables question, no?

Comment: Yes actually that makes sense. You put it in the right perspective for me, thank you!